# Changing id field to a date field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm creating a todo list in Rails and right now, I have the lists come up as their ID in the url, for example:

```
    root/todo_lists/4
```

But as the application evolves, I am wanting to replace the ID system with a date system (since on the home page, there is a calendar, rather than a list of todo lists). So clicking on a day in the calendar, will take me to the post of that day.

Now the calendar is `Rails simple_calendar` and the individual links to the days are in `YYYY-MM-DD` format. This is fine. I know that when I create a todo list, I can get the same formatting with (for example):

```
    TodoList.last.created_at.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
```

Which outputs a date in the format, YYYY-MM-DD.

So I need to know how I can change the `ID` in the new list from 3, for example, to something like `2015-09-08`.

I will try to figure out how to link from the `simple_calendar` to the post URL, but this is the first issues at the moment.

Comment: Are you trying to use a different routing system, for example: root/todo_lists/something_else? Or are you trying to convert integer data into data data?

Comment: See in your TodoList table created_at field will be present by default. So as far as I know you will have to create an index on created_at field and then create a route same as yours but the problem with this is that there will be multiple todo lists for the same day hence creating issues. Better is to let them be as they are right now . Home page a particular todo list will be there and days of the month will be shown. So when you click on a day just filter out by the posts for that particular days using a where query. This is the easiest way to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to inspect [to_param](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/to_param) method.

Something like this will help:

```
class TodoList < AR::Base
  # your code here

  def to_param
    "#{id}_{created_at.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')}"
  end
end
```

So, the params will have not only id, but date too:

```
5_1991-03-15
6_1991-03-15
```

and so on